# ls /Desktop command is not entering into desktop

Tags: kali-linux, ls, desktop

my kali linux is not working correctly

```
$ls
Desktop Documents Music
$ls Desktop/
```

Comment: What makes you say something is not working correctly?  Edit your question with more detail.

Comment: Show us what happened. Show us what you expected. and read https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5530/yet-another-kali-discussion-working-title?r=SearchResults&s=2|28.0841

Answer (score 2):

Use `cd` not `ls` to go into Desktop directory or Music or Documents.

Your command returns nothing because your Desktop directory is probably empty.

So if you are at your home directory and you do the following:

```
#This returns nothing if your Desktop directory is empty.
$ ls Desktop/ 

#Print your working directory.
$ pwd
``
So go into Desktop directory first using `cd Desktop`
then use `ls`. If your command returns nothing is is because your Desktop directory is empty.
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are at your Home directory, then both commands should work. Otherwise try:

```
$ ls ~/Desktop

$ ls ~/Music
```

Good Luck